# Textures don't show on render

Tags: rendering, texturing, transparency

https://blenderartists.org/t/textures-dont-show-when-rendering/1151729/2

I've been having trouble getting the textures to show up while rendering a character I've been working on. It'll show up while on the texture view but when I go to render, it'll be completely black or transparent. How do I fix the textures not rendering.

Comment: Can you add a picture of your material nodes to the question? Do you have a light in your scene?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so here's your problem:
[image]

Your image node settings for your textures are set to "Clip" when they should be "Repeat". As you can see by my screenshot, it now works.

Comment: Thx for help. Does that work for all the problems like that or is more complex than that?

Comment: For the most part, yes. You virtually always want that option to be set to Repeat. That's why it's the default option. ;-)

Comment: Honestly I've never noticed. I just assumed that the picture would work just throwing it in there, plus images as planes does the hard part of using a texture in cycles.